# Clearing the local storage of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey Guys I have a html page with two buttons. I have **enabled local storage** so that the 2 buttons doesn't loose its colour when the page is refreshed. But the issue  I'm facing is that, when one button is clicked the other doesnt loose it colour. What i want to achieve is that, when one button is clicked another button should loose its colour. Then i can know which button is active. I have tried many methods but failed. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
    .button {
      box-shadow: -2px 2px blanchedalmond, -1px 1px orange, -1px 1px orange;
      margin-top: 280px; 
      margin-left: 420px;    
      background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128); 

      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 30px 35px;
    }

    .button-green, .button:focus {
      background-color:rgba(10, 170, 10, 0.952);
    }



    .button1 {
      box-shadow: -2px 2px blanchedalmond, -1px 1px orange, -1px 1px orange;
      margin-top: 280px; 
      margin-left: 420px;    
      background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128); 

      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 30px 35px;

    }

    .button1-green, .button1:focus {
      background-color:rgba(10, 170, 122, 0.952);
    }


  </style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="x-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Terravision pty ltd</title>


  </head>
  <body>
  
  <div style = "position:fixed; left:-300px; top:-100px;">

<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <form id="form" method="get" action="" >     
    <button  class="button" >Lights On</button>
    </form>

    <form id="form1" method="get" action="" >
    <button  class="button1" >Lights Off</button>
    </form>

<!----------------------------------------------------------------------------->



<script>
 

    if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted') === 'yes') {
            for(const button of document.getElementsByClassName('button')) {
                button.classList.add('button-green')
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted', 'yes');
        })  
     

if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted1') === 'yes') {
            for(const button of document.getElementsByClassName('button1')) {
                button.classList.add('button1-green')
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted1', 'yes');
        })


</script>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code to something like this. I put notes inside.

```
<style>
.clicked {background-color: green;} 
</style>
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
<button id="button2">Button1</button>
<script>
// this will hold all buttons that you want to control
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
// iterate them
for (var i=0; i < btns.length; i++) { 
    // add click event listener 
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        // remove the current clicked class (if present)
        if(document.querySelector('.clicked')) {document.querySelector('.clicked').classList.remove('clicked')};
        // save the current button to locasorage
        localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted', this.id); 
        // mark the clicked button
        markBtn();
    });
}
// this will mark a button if it exist on local storage
function markBtn () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted')) {
        let clickedBtn = localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted');
        document.querySelector('#'+clickedBtn).classList.add('clicked');
    }
}
// don't forget to call this function when page load
markBtn();
</script>
```

Edit as for comments:

```
<style>
.clicked {background-color: green;} 
</style>
<form>
<button id="button1">Button1</button>
</form>
<form>
<button id="button2">Button2</button>
</form>
<form>
    <button id="button3">Button3</button>
</form>
<script>
// this will hold all buttons that you want to control
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
// iterate them
for (var i=0; i < btns.length; i++) { 
    // add click event listener 
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        // remove the current clicked class (if present)
        if(document.querySelector('.clicked')) {document.querySelector('.clicked').classList.remove('clicked')};
        // save the current button to locasorage
        localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted', this.id); 
        // mark the clicked button
        markBtn();
    });
}
// this will mark a button if it exist on local storage
function markBtn () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted')) {
        let clickedBtn = localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted');
        document.querySelector('#'+clickedBtn).classList.add('clicked');
    }
}
// don't forget to call this function when page load
markBtn();
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer. But i want to put my buttons inside a form as they need to access a file in my server.

Comment: With this code you can change your markup to anything... This works with button's id so when you click the button it will save the current id on locastorage of the client. Check update

Answer (score 1):

Ok so basically what you are missing is to remove the non-pressed button class if its active.

First you click button 1 and have it green.
Then you click button 2 and have it green.
But the problem is that now both buttons are green.

what you need to do is when clicking button, search for button1-green class.
If it exists, then remove it.

And the same goes for the button 1. ( search for button-green and remove it)

Something like:

```
   if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted') === 'yes') {
            for(const button of document.getElementsByClassName('button')) {
                button.classList.add('button-green')
            }
           var button1 = document.getElementByClassName("button1-green");
           if(button1) button1.classList.remove("button1-green");
     }
        document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted', 'yes');
        })
```

Comment: I tried this, now the colour of " Lights off " goes away. But now when i click the Lights off the Light on colour is still there and there is no colour applied to lights off. This is what i added if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted1') === 'yes'){
for(const button of document.getElementsByClassName('button1')) {
button.classList.add('button1-green')
}
var button = document.getElementByClassName("button-green");
if(button) button.classList.remove("button-green");
}
document.getElementById('form1').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted1','yes');})

Comment: I think the problem is that the colour exits in the local storage and thus it just cannot be erased until the local storage for that button is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same formSubmitted key on local storage for both buttons.
So when you set formSubmitted as 'yes' you get in both if statements and add button-green and button-green1 to the buttons.

Try using two different variables for the two forms.
something like formSubmitted and form1Submitted would work.

Comment: So sorry man. My original code was like that. I think it was a typo. Now i made edits to my code. But the real issue I'm facing is that, the button 1 colour doesn't dissapear when button 2 is pressed. So basically if i press lights on, it will be green and if I press Lights offs , it will also turn green. So now i have two buttons which are green. Thanks

Comment: Oh I see.
No problem.